# Access Control Allow Origin error with WordPress subdomain

Tags: wordpress, azure, iis, cloud, hosting

I'm facing a problem with my WordPress website, it has a subdomain, blog.domain.com, when I access the blog I get the following error in my console:

Access to Font at `www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf` from origin `blog.domain.com` has been blocked by CORS policy: No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource.

Currently, my website is hosted in Azure, I tried activating the option "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - Cors" in my hosting options, it solved the issue, but it made the website a lot slower (16 sec), so I'm looking for an alternative to this issue.

If anyone has any idea how I can resolve this, I am opened to suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me which kinds of azure service you have used to host the wordpress? Azure web app or Azure VM?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used Azure web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the windows azure web app, I suggest you could try to access below url:

https://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

Then you should go to the site\wwwroot and find the web.config file and add below config setting:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: If you feel my answer help you to solve the issue, please mark it as answer to let other folks who faces the same issue to find the solution more easily. Thank you.

Comment: I just did. Thanks again :)